# Recieving User Informations from user_id with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreign-keys

I have one thing to ask to all of you.I have one model class that is recieves some texts from database.In this row also I have user_id colounm.I need to recieve userInformation with another model file for each post how can i do this?

I explain what I want:
I have table like this:
id[PK]  title   content   user_id[Foreign Key]

example data:
1 |  loreim ipsum | hello its new content text | 1

also I have a user table
id[PK] username avatar

example data
1 | admin | avatar.gif

I am recieving datas from first table but I need to recieve author user's username and avatar.How can i do this in controller.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Maybe posting the relevant bits of code would help, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `JOIN`, it looks something like this using CI's [Active Record class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) (depending on what exactly you want to do):

```
$query = $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = posts.user_id')->get('posts');
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->post_title;
    echo $row->username;
}
```

You could also query the users table separately for each post and store the user object in a property of each post, like:

```
// foreach $post
$post->user = $this->db->where('id', $post->user_id)->get('users')->row();
```

...or something, just make sure not to run more queries than necessary (for example, you could fetch all the users in one query where the user id is in an array of post user ids, no need for a separate query for each post if you do it this way).

I would also recommend considering an ORM like [Datamapper for Codeigniter](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/) to take the hassle out of writing joins and complex relationships. It might seem like overkill, but I prefer it over CI's Active Record class (even though it uses it internally), even for small projects.

Comment: Thank you sir.It worked for me! I am using JOIN method in this case =))